# issue : when save drawable or bitmap on sdcard?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, sd-card

I am trying to save image in sd card like as :

```
Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
imageView.draw(canvas);


 file = new File(folder, "temp.jpg");
 try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmapP.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        return file.toString();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
```

Now i get image like as:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image);
```

I got bitmap, But my bitmap quality is going blur...
What's i doing wrong ?

Any one can help me?
thanks

Comment: is the quality any better if you use CompressFormat.PNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JPEG` is not a lossless format. It is normal that it gets blurred little bit. Other options are [Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP](http://code.google.com/speed/webp/) & Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG

Answer (score 0):

try to get bitmap from file like this:

> ```
>       bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(file.toURL().openStream());
> ```

hope this will help you! if you haven't already found an answer!

Comment: Thanks for giving answer, but sorry friend Your answer is not useful to me...hope will other get solution from your answer....again thanks